# Where can I find Rock Smash in Pokemon Alpha Sapphire/Omega Ruby?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Where do I find it? I need it for the tunnel east of Rustboro City.
Or could anyone help me to get to the next town? I've done all the missions e.g Devon parts.

Answer (score 1):

You will receive Rock Smash (HM06 in ORAS) in Mauville City from Wally's Uncle after you defeated Wally in front of the Gym.

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mauville_City#Pok.C3.A9mon_Omega_Ruby_and_Alpha_Sapphire)